# Get the OpenSSL::PKey::EC key size in Ruby

Tags: ruby, certificate, x509certificate, public-key, ecdsa

I have the following `Base64` encoded ECDSA certificate and I am trying to get the EC key size from the information contained in it using the Ruby (version 2.5.x):

```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```

I am reading the documentation about the `OpenSSL::PKey::EC`, however I am not able to find a way how to calculate the key size.

For the RSA certificates, I can use the following:

```
cert = Base64.decode64(b64)
certificate = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new cert
key_size = certificate.public_key.n.num_bytes * 8
```

But how to get it from the Elliptic Curve? Is it the degree of the group associated with the curve field?:

```
cert = Base64.decode64(b64)
certificate = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new cert
key_size = certificate.public_key.group.degree
```

It would match the curve `prime256v1`, but I am not sure if this is correct assumption.

Answer (score 0):

certificate.public_key.group.degree works for secp384r1 as well, but I'm not sure that is true for all curves.

I use the following ugly hack which works for both RSA and DC keys:

```
key_size = certificate.public_key.to_text.gsub(/.*\((.*) bit\).*/m, '\1')
```

Not very efficient but it works.